# Why is this percolator query invalid?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8086/?pretty
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Selene",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.5.0",
    "build_hash" : "544816042d40151d3ce4ba4f95399d7860dc2e92",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-03-23T14:30:58Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

With this mapping:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8086/watches/watches/_mapping?pretty
{
  "watches" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "watches" : {
        "properties" : {
          "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_shape",
            "tree_levels" : 5
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A regular query is fine:

```
$ curl -XGET -d '
> {
>     "query": {
>         "filtered": {
>             "filter": {
>                 "and": [
>                     {
>                         "geo_shape": {
>                             "location": {
>                                 "shape": {
>                                     "type": "envelope",
>                                     "coordinates": [[-180, 90], [180, -90]]
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 ]
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ' 'http://localhost:8086/watches/watches/_search?pretty'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "watches",
      "_type" : "watches",
      "_id" : "berlin",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":
{
    "name": "Wind & Wetter, Berlin, Germany",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [13.400544, 52.530286]
    }
}

    } ]
  }
}
```

Put registering a similar percolator query fails:

```
$ curl -XPUT -d '
> {
>     "query": {
>         "filtered": {
>             "filter": {
>                 "and": [
>                     {
>                         "geo_shape": {
>                             "location": {
>                                 "shape": {
>                                     "type": "envelope",
>                                     "coordinates": [[-180, 90], [180, -90]]
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 ]
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ' 'http://localhost:8086/watches/.percolator/mypercolatorquery?pretty'
{
  "error" : "PercolatorException[[watches] failed to parse query [mypercolatorquery]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[watches] Field [location] is not a geo_shape]; ",
  "status" : 500
}
```

Why and how can I register my query against the percolator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in Elasticsearch triggered by the option `index.percolator.map_unmapped_fields_as_string: true`

See issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10500